# Displaying row and column indexes for image in ArcGIS DEsktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

I have been struggling with how to  find the row number and column number for
particular points in any raster map.

My raster details:

```
columns and rows:  720 360 
cell size (0.5, 0.5)
```

How can I know the row number and column number by pointing the cursor at any location in the map?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you could add the information to the attribute table:

[HowTo:  Locate the column and row of a point within a raster](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/38007)

using the field calculator or Spatial Analyst

Comment: NO,this if you have something to add.My case is how to display x and y

Comment: @WafaAlyaari The method that the answer describes _is_ a way to display the X and Y. It embeds that information into each row by adding x and y fields.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify which tool you are using. There are a lot which can provide you such kind of information and more reg raster maps. QGIS is pretty good GUI and [image: qgis raster query]

there is also another tools such as GRASS GIS,iview(OSSIM) etc which provides you the information.

Comment: Thanks for this. So I have to learn  QGIS.is there a way through Arcgis 9.3

Comment: the tag is arcgis so I would assume he is using arcgis...

Comment: however,where is the number of pixcl and lines in your attached map

Comment: sorry its for qgis. ossim iview provides row,col number and pixel value.

Comment: I have downloaded QGIS and I have my map append how can I know the number of pixel and lins

Comment: see the coordinate in the status bar

Comment: but that is the coordinats -180 180 -90 90  not pixel 720 and line  360.

Answer (score 0):

ok. try this. http://download.osgeo.org/ossim/installers/windows/ossimplanet-installer-1.8.3.exe which gives you a iview tool as i told earlier

[image: iview]

line and sample highlighted are row and column

Hope this helps

Comment: It seems that there is no solution within GIS. Because even in QGIS you see the pixel and line and then you do not see the latitude and longitude or latitude coordinates.

Comment: No I disagree. Because providing such features are not a difficult task. Some users(individual/company) need to ask for such features in open source projects. Maybe its of less priority. I dont like to make you install another tool. But I had seen another tool which provide the functionality called "ILWIS". I guess QGIS hasn't concentrated more on the imagery/raster data. OSSIM works mainly for imagery. so the pixel(x,y) is important. and ILWIS has raster operations such as classification,clustering etc. so it also has the feature

Comment: maybe ArcGIS also has it because it has more raster processing algorithms.